# knapsack ComputerGraphics cg opengl

Tags: c, opengl, glut, opengl-4

I'm trying to implement knapsack using OpenGL. I'm generating balls of given weight and profit taking values from the user, and then draw balls on the screen. I want to send the balls which are selected into a box but I'm not at all able to move the ball. Can you suggest a way to move a ball from point A to point B forming a trajectory in 2d?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JIowM4NGLGOFWKosk6VTIB3SDGF4D_WI

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Could you please share what you have already done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) is what you need.